# Who is the dead woman in the casket?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-specialist

Sharon Stone's character in [The Specialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Specialist) is named May Munro.  She uses the alias Adrian Hastings to infiltrate a local crime organization to seek revenge for the murder of her parents.

Adrian Hastings fakes her death and there is a scene displaying her funeral notice in the newspaper.

There was an actual funeral taking place with an older woman in the casket.

Later in the film, May describes how she was successful in faking her death and that she placed her identification in the purse of a woman who died in the emergency room.

> Poor lady O.D.'d in the emergency room. I dropped my wallet in her
>   purse... ...and here I am.

To my knowledge, it's never explained how there happened to be an actual funeral for "Adrian Hastings" if she didn't die. The woman in the casket at the funeral had mourners and one of them (who appears to be a nun) mentions her charity work with children.  This leads me to believe that she would not have overdosed in an emergency room. Mourners at the funeral obviously knew who she was.

**Was this supposed to be the woman who May dropped off her wallet with after she died?  If so, how would this be possible?  Was this woman coincidentally named Adrian Hastings?**